# window.open from OWA in Safari and IE

Tags: office-js

Our Outlook office.js add-in opens an external website using `window.open()`. That other website opens correctly in Outlook 2013, Outlook 2016, Outlook for Mac and OWA in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. It does not open correctly in OWA for Safari and IE, but if you copy the URL and paste it into a new Safari or IE window, it works.

Interestingly if `outlook.office.com` is added as a Trusted Site in IE, then this works in IE.

When I say that the opened window does not work, I mean it does some checking for valid OS, browser and Flash (somehow) and this fails in the scenarios already given (but succeeds in a new browser window).

It seems the calling context is different for OWA in Safari and IE and for IE that context is corrected when outlook.office.com is a Trusted Site. Since Safari does not seem to have an equivalent mechanism as Trusted Sites, this workaround is not even an option for Safari.

Any ideas what the issue might be? Thanks.

**Update:** I just updated my Safari to version 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7) and this issue no longer occurs for Safari OWA. In fact every combination of `window.open()` call or Dialog API call, with or without a redirect page in between, works. Somebody out there did a great job!

Answer (score 0):

Using `window.open()` with Office Web Add-ins introduces a number of issues, including the one you ran into. The guidance is to use the [Dialog API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui) included with Office.js instead.

Using the Dialog API is very straightforward. You can read more and see some example scenarios in [Use the Dialog API in your Office Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins).

Comment: I tried using the Dialog API to load an HTML file hosted on the add-in's domain that immediately redirects to the other site and this had the same result. I will study the example scenarios to see what I might be doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you handle that redirect inside the Office.initialize() function so you're sure Outlook has wired up the bits behind the scene before you leave that page.

Comment: Please be sure that you specify [app domains](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/add-in-manifests#specify-domains-you-want-to-open-in-the-add-in-window) in your manifest when using the Dialog API.

Comment: I wired up an html page in my add-in's domain, opened the page using the Dialog API and did the `window.location.replace(theexternalurl)` in `Office.initialize` but the page still does not work in IE OWA. Since the redirect page is hosted on my domain, I believe no app domain listing is needed. Interestingly while a simple `window.open()` call works for Outlook 2016, if I use this redirect method for Outlook 2016 it does not work. Any other tips? As I said before, adding `outlook.office.com` (or `outlook.office365.com`) to the Trusted Sites makes this work for IE OWA. What does that tell me?

Comment: An extra detail: when I click the button that opens a window using the Dialog API, I get a prompt "MyApp wants to display a new window" with two buttons, "Accept" and "Ignore". I obviously click "Accept". But why does this prompt appear? Thanks again.

Comment: Update: No matter what I try a proper context redirect will not work with OWA in IE and as it turns out Edge, without adding outlook.office.com to the IE Trusted Sites. Conversely redirect works in Firefox, Chrome, and now Safari (after the last update) without any settings tweaks.